# How do I the change label to visible when checkbox is checked and hide when unchecked?

Tags: angularjs, vuforia

I want checkbox-3 to control the visibility of label-1 depending on whether it's checked or unchecked.

```
$scope.check = function () {
  if ($scope.view.wdg['checkbox-3'].checked) {  
    $scope.view.wdg["label-1"].visible = true;
  } else {
    $scope.view.wdg["label-1"].visible = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: The AngularJS API docs of 'ngShow` shows an [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#examples) to show/hide an element on checkbox state. I think its helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS, you can use "ng-show" directive to show or hide elements.
For example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" />
  <label ng-show="isChecked">Checked!</label>
</body>
```